# Add a Sent by User filter column to the Elementor Submissions Page/Tab

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to add a filterable column to the Submissions page of Elementor, so that I can filter the forms that have been sent by User name, so far I have tried writing the following code but it breaks my site:

```
function add_user_filter_to_submissions_page() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id === 'elementor-pro_page_e-form-submissions' ) {
        $users = get_users();
        ?>
        <label for="user_filter"><?php _e( 'Filter by User:', 'elementor-pro' ); ?></label>
        <select name="user_filter" id="user_filter">
            <option value=""><?php _e( 'All Users', 'elementor-pro' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ( $users as $user ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" <?php selected( isset( $_GET['user_filter'] ) && $_GET['user_filter'] === (string) $user->ID ); ?>>
                    <?php echo esc_html( $user->display_name ); ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_user_filter_to_submissions_page' );

function modify_submissions_query( $query ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id === 'elementor-pro_page_e-form-submissions' && isset( $_GET['user_filter'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['user_filter'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'author', $_GET['user_filter'] );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_submissions_query' );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - but I don't have the answer. I'm trying to count the number of submissions from inside a shorcode function, but I am struggling with that as there seems to be zero documentation on it.

Submissions look like a custom post type, but when I get_post_tyoes() I can't see it. Any ideas? If I can figure out what they are I might be able to help you with the filtering.